# smart pointers and iterating with auto

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is it possible to use auto for iteration purposes as so?

Code produces error, but I wonder if maybe it is possible.  Line with error is commented.  I'm curious because I like smart pointers but I'd like to type less... and I like the idea of quick prototyping with c++.

```
        deque<shared_ptr<Vehicle>> data;
    data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("aba")) );
    data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("bobo")) );
    data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("cici")) );
    data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("dede")) );
    data.push_back( shared_ptr<Vehicle>(new Vehicle("efee")) );


    for( auto i = data.begin(); i != data.end; )   //error
    {
        if( (*i)->getName() == "cici" )
        {
            i = data.erase(i);          //Only works with C++11. i on left side is next valid pos.  

            break;
        }
        else
            ++i; 
    }
```

Comment: What's your actual question, though?

Comment: Should read data.end(); ?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: sorry moof2k, your correction was the key... changed to () and works.  I would have given you the answer if you posted as answer... but Christophe post as answer first.  I upvoted you though...

Comment: I'd like to hear why this was down voted.  Just because you didn't get the points for being selected as the answer, doesn't mean you should be vindictive.  Especially since I gave everyone points that provided the correct answer and explained in all fairness why I gave the points to Chris.

Comment: @code The question is downvoted because it's a bad question, not because people are vindictive. *You* aren't downvoted, the question is. The question basically says "Can I do this? I tried but I get an error", and then it includes some code that does not produce an error. It doesn't even say what the (supposed) error is. It also doesn't show any evidence that you've tried to solve the problem yourself (although that's hard to say without knowing what the problem is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you use auto:

```
for( auto i = data.begin(); i != data.end() ; ) {  //  look at condition
    ...
}
```

You could even use range-for if you wouldn't need the the iterator for erasure:

```
for (auto& sptr : data) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `auto` works fine, the problem is there are several errors in your code

```
for( auto i = data.begin(); i != data.end; )
```

should be

```
for( auto i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); )
```

And

```
i = list.erase(i);
```

The variable `list` is not defined here, I will presume you meant

```
i = data.erase(i);
```

Comment: yes, you are correct.  Sorry the other poster beat you by a few minutes.  I'll upvote you. Thanks!!